# Solving the volume of the parallelopiped in IIT JEE Advanced 2023

Tags: vectors, 3d

IIT JEE has been asking novel interesting questions at ancillary levels for the Engineering Entrance Test in India. Some of these math questions are quite thought provoking. In the just held (05-June-2023) exam they asked:

**The question**

Let P be a plane $\sqrt{3}x+2y+3z=16$ and
let the set

$S=\{\alpha \vec i+\beta \vec j+ \gamma \vec j $, $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2=1$, the perpendicular distance of point $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$ from the plane P be  $\frac{7}{2}.\}$

Let vectors $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w $ are  three distinct vectors  in $S$ such that $|\vec u-\vec v|= |\vec v- \vec w|=|\vec u-\vec w|.$ Find the volume of the parallelopiped determined by vectors $\vec u, \vec v$ and $\vec w$.

**My proposed solution:**

Note that vectors $\vec u, \vec v, \vec w$ are unit vectors additionally they are mutually equally inclined to each other $\hat u. \hat v = \hat v. \hat w=\hat u. \hat w=\cos \theta$ (let).
The perpendicular distance connection gives is $$\sqrt{3}\alpha +2 \beta+ 3 \gamma=2,30......(*)$$

Visualize, $\vec r= \sqrt{3}\vec i+ 2\vec j+3 \vec k$, then $(*)$ is equivalent to $\vec r. \hat u= \vec r. \hat v= \vec r. \hat w= 2~ (\text{choose}) \implies \cos \phi = \frac{1}{2}.$

Here, $\vec r$ is equally inclined at angle  $\phi$ to each of $\hat u, \hat v, \hat w.
$, so we can write
$$\hat r= \lambda [ \hat u +\hat v+\hat w]\implies 1=\lambda^2[3+6 \cos \theta].$$
Taking dot product  by $\hat u$ in above, we get $$\cos \phi=\sqrt{\frac{1+2\cos \theta}{3}}.....(**).$$
From here we get $\cos \theta =-\frac{1}{8}.$
Finally, the  volume $V$ of the parallelopiped is given by $$V=[\hat u, \hat v, \hat w]=(1-\cos \theta)\sqrt{1+2\cos \theta}=\frac{9\sqrt{3}}{16}.$$

Is this answer correct? What could be other ways of finding it.